# how to show database table in wxListCtrl

Tags: wxwidgets

i m just a beginner and i m using c++, wxwidget and mysql
manually i m capable to add data in ListCtrl but when i m filling data in ListCtrl , conversion showing some problem
i know how to add data in wxListCtrl
ex-

```
data_list_control->InsertColumn(0,wxT("Country"),2);
data_list_control->SetColumnWidth(0, 110);
data_list_control->InsertColumn(1,wxT("State"),2);
data_list_control->SetColumnWidth(1, 110);
data_list_control->InsertColumn(2,wxT("Zip"),2);
data_list_control->SetColumnWidth(2, 160);
long index = data_list_control->InsertItem(0, wxT("India"));
data_list_control->SetItem(index, 1, wxT("U.p"));
data_list_control->SetItem(index, 2, wxT("208005"));
```

with the help of this we can get
India U.p 208005 in wxListCtrl but when i am filling this with database then conversion of varchar to wxString creating a problem, it is showing all the result but in garbage form
i m doing mysql connectivity, look at this

```
while((row=mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{

long index=data_list_control->InsertItem(i,wxT(row[i]));
i++;
for(j=1;j<num_fields;j++)
{

data_list_control->SetItem(index,j,wxT(row[j]));
}
}
```

if database have three row then listctrl also showing three row but value are in unexpected form..
i only want to know how to convert varchar, int , long or any database data type to wxString format.

Comment: actually i got the solution of this.... no need to bother about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    List_Ctrl_Data obj1 ;

                         MYSQL_RES *database_table_data;
                         database_table_data=obj1.getdata();
                         if (database_table_data==NULL)
                         {
                             int decision = wxMessageBox(wxT("CAN NOT CONNECT TO DATABASE"), wxT("Message"),  wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION, NULL,  -1, -1);
                         }
                         else if(mysql_num_rows(database_table_data)==0)
                         {
                             int decision = wxMessageBox(wxT("database has nothing to show"), wxT("Message"),  wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION, NULL,  -1, -1);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             int num_fields;
                             MYSQL_ROW row;
                             num_fields = mysql_num_fields(database_table_data);
                             long i=0;
                             int j;
                             while((row=mysql_fetch_row(database_table_data)))
                             {
                                 const char* chars1 = row[0];
                                 wxString mystring1(chars1, wxConvUTF8);
                                 long index=data_list_control->InsertItem(i,mystring1);
                                 i++;
                                 for(j=1;j<num_fields;j++)
                                 {
                                     const char* chars2=row[j];
                                     wxString mystring2(chars2,wxConvUTF8);
                                     data_list_control->SetItem(index,j,mystring2);
                                 }
                             }
                         }
```

}
void login::onbuttonclick(wxCommandEvent & WXUNUSED(event))
{

```
Close(true);
```

}